# What is the page limit for the Camera-Ready version of the paper?

Tags: conference

My paper was accepted by a conference. The paper is limited to 11 pages at the time of submission. But now when I add author information, the paper becomes 12 pages. But I did not see the page requirement of Camera-Ready version. Is the page limit of Camera-Ready the same as when it was submitted?

The website of the conference is: https://hpca-conf.org/2022/camera-ready-instructions/

**The reason I asked this question is because I found that a paper last year was 12 pages.** https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/9065598
And I just heard someone say that the Camera-Ready version is often one page longer than when it was submitted. I'm very sorry.

I sent an email to the conference party in the morning, but there is no accurate reply yet.

Thanks!

Comment: In most cases: just stick to the limits and do not bother others: just remove a few words, I'm sure it is possible.

Comment: Even if the page limit was 11 pages in the previous year, it could have happened that changes made by the editorial team pushed a 11 page "camera ready" submitted by the authors to 12 pages.. I have seen this happen with Springer -- the paper created using the camera ready template was not the same as the final formatted paper after Springer's edits. The expectation was that the length while submitting was within the limits, even though the formatting done afterwards pushed it above it.

Answer (score 4):

Nobody can know more than what the website says. You'll have to make a professional decision what you think is the right number and how much you want to argue with them if you submit 12 pages when they were expecting 11.

That's part of being a professional: Sometime you have to make decisions with not very much guidance.

Comment: ... or, you ask for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, the page limit for camera-ready papers is the same as that for the initial submission. It's quite typical that one has to add things to a paper in response to reviewer feedback -- not only the author header --, so one often has to compress parts of the paper anyways.

However, one can always ask the program chairs if an additional page would be OK. In several situations, I have received a positive response to such a request. It's advisable to ask such a question as early as possible, since the program chairs might need some time to make the decision (including communication with the publishers).

Comment: This answer is not wrong, but note that most of the time there is abosolutely no need to ask for additional pages: it is up to the author and part of their job to respect the limits. I suspect that most conference chairs and editors would be rather frustrated / annoyed if everybody started asking for exceptions to the rules. Except in exceptional cases ;)

Comment: @Louic Conversely, virtual ink + space is cheap and conferences often have some flexibility with granting extra pages. It may take them a brief mail to sort this out -- potentially a much smaller effort than trimming down a paper to comply with the somewhat arbitrary page limits.